# Trace of Frobenius on $p$-adic Tate module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p>0$ with $q$ elements.  Denote $K=W(k)[1/p]$. 
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $W(k)$ with good reduction. 
Choose a lifting $\mathrm{Frob} \in \mathrm{Gal}(\bar K/K)$  of the $q$-th power map on $\overline{k}$ such that $\chi(\mathrm{Frob})=1$, here $\chi$ is the $p$-adic cyclotomic character.
Recall that the trace of $\mathrm{Frob}$ on $\ell$-adic Tate module does not depend on the choice of the prime number $\ell(\neq p)$ and is equal to $ a_q := 1 + \# k - \# E(k) $.

Question: Is the trace of  $\mathrm{Frob}$ on the $p$-adic Tate module still equal to $a_q$?

Comment: Yes; as the corresponding representation will be crystalline.

Comment: The $\bmod $ reduction is an isomorphism $E[\ell^\infty] \to \widetilde{E}[\ell^\infty]$ so the matrices in $GL_2(\Bbb{Z}_\ell)$ of $Frob|_{E[\ell^\infty]}$ and its reduction are the same, the OP is asking what does the matrix of $Frob |_{E[\ell^p]}\in Aut(E[p^\infty])\cong GL_2(\Bbb{Z}_p)$ look like and if its trace is related to $tr(Frob|_{E[\ell^\infty]})$

Comment: Why do you even expect the trace of $\mathrm{Frob}$ to be independent of the choice of lift?

Comment: If E is ordinary, then the action is upper triangularizable with a quotient determined by the reduction, and a sub determined by that quotient and the cyclotomic character, so the trace is determined by how the galois element acts on p^n ropts of unity, which presumably depends on the lift of element in galois but not on the choice of lift of elliptic curve

Comment: Thanks. You are right, the trace does depend on the choice of the lifting of the Frobenius map. Maybe, I need to consider those lifting $\mathrm{Frob}$ such that $\chi(Frob)=1$, here $\chi$ is the cyclotomic character.

Comment: If you would like to recover $a_q$ in the crysalline supersingular case you need to take the trace of the $\Phi$ operator on $\text{D}_{cris}(V_E)$ where $V_E$ is the $p$-adic Galois representation.